# Nitrogen session

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

In all my nitrogen pages i use the following semantic :

```
main() -> 
case wf:user() /= undefined of 
    true  -> main_authorized();
    false -> wf:redirect_to_login("/login")
end.
```

When the user is logged in and in a page containing a form if the session timeout he can still do the form post, leading to some issues on my website logic since an unlogged user should be redirected to login page, is there any way i can achieve this behavior without have to go through all my pages event function and look for this case?

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 4):

Nitrogen provides the application developer with the ability to define and set an authorization callback module.

Instead of having the `main/0` logic you describe in each of your page handlers you can define an authorization handler like in the following Gist I wrote in February:
https://gist.github.com/830529

The `init/2` function in the `security_handler` callback module you define (assuming you hook it in upon startup with `nitrogen:handler/2`) will be executed before the `main/0` function in your page handler.

To be sure no part of the POST page handler is executed you should call `wf:status_code/1` with 401 as argument. Then specify the appropriate login page is served on 401 responses as per your web server's configuration.